# React quill custom image handler module causing typing issues with the editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill, react-quill

I am using [React Quill](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill) as the text editor. This works fine until I add the custom image handler. If I add the image handler as below, I can't type into the editor. Typing lose focus on every single keypress.

```
const modules = {
    toolbar: {
        container: [
            [{'header': [3, 4, 5, 6, false]}],
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote', 'code'],
            [{color: []}, {background: []}],
            [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}, {'indent': '-1'}, {'indent': '+1'}],
            ['link', 'image'],
            ['clean']
        ],
        handlers: {
            image: imageHandler
        }
    },
    clipboard: {
        // toggle to add extra line breaks when pasting HTML:
        matchVisual: false,
    }
};

function imageHandler() {
    console.log("custom image handler");
}
```

If I comment out the `image: imageHandler`, editor works perfectly. Here is the [codesanbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-haze-oggig)

Am I writing the custom module correctly?

Comment: Just wondering if you're using react-quill for a new project? We've been using it on our app over the last few years and it has been very poorly supported. I'd steer clear from it if possible.

Comment: @WilliamPark Yes it's a new project. what would you recommend? All open source text editors have poor support.

Comment: Take a look at Draft or Slate. I'm in the process of switching quill over to a slate editor.

Comment: @WilliamPark if you are concerned about "it has been very poorly supported", then you should remove 'draft.js' from the list. Other options you may consider are: Nib(nibedit.com) and Article editor(paid, https://imperavi.com/article/)

Comment: Yeah Draft hasn't been well supported lately either, that is totally fair. It has had commits over the last few months unlike react-quill that hasn't received any in years. We have went with Slate. It's a bit more work to set up but it feels very flexible in its capabilities.

Comment: @WilliamPark Slate is in beta right now, aren't you afraid of some breaking changes when they get into real build?

Comment: Right now I'm just working on a proof of concept and evaluating slate. Nothing I'm building right now is heading into production any time soon. It could happen, but I doubt any major API changes will happen with slate's new version at this point. I will say though the lack of documentation for the new version is a pain point though.

Answer (score 19):

**TL;DR**

This is what helped me:

https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill/issues/309#issuecomment-654768941
https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill/issues/309#issuecomment-659566810

---

The modules object passed directly into the component makes it render all modules on every keypress. To make it stop, you have to use the concept of memoization in react. You can use the useMemo hook to wrap the modules and then pass that into the component.

```
  const modules = useMemo(() => ({
    toolbar: {
      container: [
        [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
        [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
        ['image', 'code-block']
      ],
      handlers: {
        image: selectLocalImage
      }
    }
  }), [])
```

and then in the component:

```
<ReactQuill placeholder="Write some text..."
  value={text}
  modules={modules}
  onChange={onChange} />
```

Answer (score 2):

`useRef() & onBlur()` is the Ultimate answer to your question.

Here is how I solved the same query.

```
   export default function QuillEditor({
      value,
      onChange
   }) {


  const [description, setDescription] = useState(value || "");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (value) {
      setDescription(value);
    }
  }, [value]);

   ....

   const quillRef = useRef(); // the solution

   ....
   const imageHandler = () => {
    // get editor
    const editor = quillRef.current.getEditor();

    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "file");
    input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
    input.click();

    input.onchange = async () => {
      const file = input.files[0];
      try {
        const link = IMAGE_LINK_HERE;
        editor.insertEmbed(editor.getSelection(), "image", link);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("upload err:", err);
      }
    };
  };


  const toolbarOptions = [
    ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
    ["code-block", "link", "image"],
    ...
  ];

  const modules = {
    toolbar: {
      container: toolbarOptions,
      handlers: {
        image: imageHandler,
      },
    },
    clipboard: {
      matchVisual: false,
    },
  };

  const handleOnBlur = () => {
    onChange(description);
  };

....


  return (
      <ReactQuill
        ref={quillRef} // must pass ref here
        value={description}
        onChange={(val) => setDescription(val)}
        onBlur={handleOnBlur}
        theme="snow"
        modules={modules}
        formats={formats}
        placeholder="Write something awesome..."
      />
    )
....
```